# Menu animation slide from top function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, jquery-animate

I would like to add a menu like the one in this demo site [Here](http://www.kingsizetheme.com/) 
it drops down from the top of the page as  you can see and i would like to know if this was done with only CSS3 or .
If someone can show me a simple function so i can go off it that would be nice!

EDIT: ok i found the code snippet for it I think , i still want to know if this is a good way to do it , and if someone can make this more simple, seems like a lot of code just for that

```
var isUp = false;
var navHeight = $('#navContainer').height();
    var hideHeight = navHeight - 50; 

$('#arrowLink a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    navHeight = $('#navContainer').height();
    hideHeight = navHeight - 50; 

    $('.tooltip').remove();
    if(!isUp){          
        $(this).find('img').attr('src',template_directory+'/images/menu_hide_arrow_bottom.png');
        $(this).find('img').attr('title',showNav);
        $( "#navContainer" ).animate({          
            top: '-='+ hideHeight + 'px'
        }, 500, "swing", function() {
            isUp = true;
        }); 
    }else{
        $(this).find('img').attr('src',template_directory+'/images/menu_hide_arrow_top.png');
        $(this).find('img').attr('title',hideNav);
        $( "#navContainer" ).animate({          
            top: "0"
        }, 500, "swing", function() {
            isUp = false;
        });             


        if($('body').hasClass('body_show_content'))
        {
             $('#mainContainer').fadeIn();  
        }   
    }
});`
```

Comment: both CSS3 and jQuery solutions are possible, but JS one looks more compatible

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done. You can use css transition/keyframes and a click event.

**Code**

html

```
<div id="container hidden">Something</div>
```

css

```
#container {
  postion:fixed;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.hidden {
  top: -25px;
}
```

js

```
$('#container').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

**Explanation**

Your menu is fixed at the top of the page. Whenever you toggle the button that displays/hides it, you can add a css class that changes the position of the element. Because you have `transition` on the element, it will animate to that new location. This can also be done using keyframes instead of transition to have more control.

[css transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

[css keyframes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this using pure css, you need to make use of `transition` effect. Check out the fiddle which gives a fair idea of something similar.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fwjww6L4/)